# Abbreviations "e." and "v." in legal documents of Argentina

Tags: abreviaturas, argentina, legislación

I'd like to know the meaning of abbreviation "e." and "v." usually seen in the resolutions and decrees of Argentina.

For example:

> e. 22/12/2016 N° 97219/16 v. 22/12/2016

here's a reference link:
https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/#!DetalleNorma/11514605/null

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems an interesting question, but you may want to add some more data. Do you have a link to a document like this one you are describing? Or an image you can upload so that we can see the whole document and have some more context? The more information you give, the better we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [Argentinian government resource](http://www.cij.gov.ar/nota-8524-Lecciones-de-redacci-n--las-abreviaciones-III.html), they mean:

- ***e.*** - "enviado" (sent)
- ***v.*** - "visto" (viewed)

So in the example given they mean that the document, dated Dec. 19 as stated in the heading, was sent on Dec. 22 and viewed by the receiver the same day.

They should've been written ***e/*** and ***v/***, with a slash instead of a dot, though; but it's an understandable mistake since almost all abbreviations use a dot.

Comment: I really thank you for your suggestion. This can be helpful.